# spring boot actuator is not working (not found) version 1.4.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I downloaded this example from spring site (https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service), I followed same steps, but if i called this URL

http://localhost:9000/health
spring boot error page is displayed

[image]

spring boot version is **1.4.1**, it should be
{"status":"UP"}, any suggestion?

application.properties

```
server.port: 9000
management.port: 9001
management.address: 127.0.0.1
```

POM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-actuator-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Logs:

[image]

Comment: Can you show your configuration file and build file (pom.XML), have you done any configuration for actuator ?

Comment: check updated question

Comment: Use port 9001, see my updated answer

Comment: nothing displayed

Comment: It should work, check the console logs when you start your application, updated in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

As per your configuration in application.properties file, actuator endpoints will be accessed by using management address and port, try this link to access them -

http://localhost:9001/health

**EDIT**: When starting the application you should be able to see actuator details in the console like below -

[image]

Comment: Is that your complete application.properties file, if not please show the compete file, have you set context-path in that ?

Comment: it's complete, please check example URL provided from spring guides

Comment: Ok. Please try with localhost instead of the management address.

Comment: It should not be. works for me with the same version.

Comment: what is the version of spring boot?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in maven cache, I removed the cache and download it again, and it is working fine now